# jQuery hover isn't functioning after divs are reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that creates a grid of divs that are generated and sent to a container div when the document loads. When one hovers over the divs, they highlight (change color). I have another function that resets the grid, allowing the user to specify the size of the grid. It's supposed to remove the divs that are currently in the container div, and replace them with divs based off of the user's input. From what I can tell this is working as intended. The only thing that *isn't* working is the hover effect once the grid is reset. Any help, or at least some direction would be much appreciated. Here is my jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/psyonix/1g9p59bx/45/

```
var d = ("<div class='square'></div>");

function createGrid(numSquares) {
    var area = $('#g_area');
    var squareSize = Math.floor(area.innerWidth() / numSquares);
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = (numSquares * numSquares); i < len; i++) {
        area.append(d);
    }


    $('.square').height(squareSize);
    $('.square').width(squareSize);
}

function resetGrid() {
    $(".square").remove();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    createGrid(32);

    $('.square').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#C8C8C8'
        });
    });
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var numSquares = prompt("Please enter the size");
        resetGrid(numSquares);
        createGrid(numSquares);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your event binding is to your original `.square` components, and when you add new ones to the DOM the event will not automatically be bound.

For the event to trigger for dynamically generated elements, you either need to

1. Rebind the `.square.hover()` event so that the new squares are binded,

or

2. Use event delegation, such as `$("#content").on("hover", ".square", function(){}` to automatically handle it for you.

Comment: If predictable, go with David Li's option 2.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and the explanation. It helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Everytime the container is emptied, the hover handler for those squares are also, lost. So you have to set the handler, everytime you createGrid !!

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-bind the events after you remove them.

To make this easier I just moved `$('.square').hover()` to inside `createGrid`:

http://jsfiddle.net/1g9p59bx/46/

Answer (score 1):

I changed some logic and now it's working.

https://jsfiddle.net/1g9p59bx/50/

```
var d = "<div class='square'></div>";
```

--

```
var len = numSquares * numSquares;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    area.append(d);
}
```

-- And finaly!! Use the function empty() instead of remove(). empty() deletes everything inside the div instead of deleting itself and then, would be impossible to bind events to an element that doesn't exist (has been removed)

```
function resetGrid() {
    $(".square").empty();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that, I appreciate it!

Comment: I changed the link to the new Jfiddle, I accidentally put the old one

Comment: It did, actually. I manually updated the code to test. Thanks for fixing the link.

Comment: Just an update, the emptying of the div doesn't remove the div from the container. What ends up happening is the divs that are sent to the container after resetting it are on top of the existing grid. If you reset the grid enough times, there is a noticeable drop in performance. What ended up working best was Tiago Garcia's suggestion of moving the `$('.square').hover()` inside `createGrid()`